# How can I get all matching values with a binary search?

Tags: c

Here is my code for finding the position of a value in a sorted array using a binary search. My problem is that the value may be present in my array more than one time, but my search only shows the position of the first match it finds. I want to output my all matching value's position. How can I solve my issue?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void aSort(int *a, int aLen){

int i, j;
for(i=0; i<aLen-1; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<aLen; j++){
        if(a[i] > a[j]){
            int temp;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
return;
}

void bSearch(int *a, int aSize, int key,int *rArr, int *ItemNum){

int start = 0;
int aEnd = aSize-1;
int mid = (start + aEnd) / 2;
*ItemNum = -1;

while(start<=aEnd){
    if(key == a[mid]){
        *ItemNum += 1;
        rArr[*ItemNum] = mid;
        break;
    }else if(a[mid] < key){
        start = mid + 1;
    }else{
        aEnd = mid - 1;
    }

    mid = (start + aEnd) / 2;
}

return;
}


int main(){
int n;
char i_type;
printf("Enter number of array element: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

int a[n];
printf("Insert array element manual or automatic?\nIf manual press 'M' or press 'A' for automatic\n");
scanf("%*c%c", &i_type);

if(i_type == 'a' || i_type == 'A'){
    printf("The array elements is:\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = rand()%100;
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

}else{
    printf("Enter %d integer value: ", n);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("The array elements is:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

aSort(a, n);
printf("\nNow the array is in ascending order:\n");
int i;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\nEnter the key value which you want to find: ");
int key, numArr, rArr[n];
scanf("%d", &key);

bSearch(a, n, key, rArr, &numArr);
if(numArr == -1){
    printf("Item not found!\n");
}else{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=numArr; i++)
        printf("Your item found in %d position.\n", rArr[i]+1);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: After finding the first position of the element, you can replace that index with a large number and again sort and do binary search. Repeat till binary search cant find the value. It is not optimal solution but it works. Or an optimal solution is checking the adjacent positions after binary search.

Comment: Hint: the other values are necessarily next to the one you've found via binary search. So once you have found one value, it should be easy to find the other ones.

Comment: Your `numArr` is not initialized properly, it doesn't point to a memory block that would hold multiple ints. Also, you should remove the `break` in the matching condition and put a `while` loop in there to continue checking adjacent elements, pushing their indexes, if they match, to your `ItemNum` array; when the adjacent elements no longer match, you should `break`. If your matching array has extra elements than needed to store the matching indexes, you should put a sentinel value in the element adjacent to the last matching element.

Answer (score 1):

If there are likely to be many repeated values: Do *two* binary searches, to find the positions of the start and the end of the run of "key" values. Don't terminate the search on exact match, and don't skip over `mid`; use `<` for the condition in one search and `<=` for the other. [The details will be tricky and may need some debugging for cases where the key isn't found or is at one end.]

If there are likely to be few repeated values: Do a single search to find the first occurrence. Then, scan linearly to find the "other end".